# Url route doesn't work as expected with IIS

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7.5, url-routing

I use url routing in my asp.net project, following is my route for product page.

```
RouteTable.Routes.MapPageRoute("product", "{language}/p/{type}/{no}/{product}", "~/Product.aspx", true);
```

expected result is as following.

http://xxxx.com/en/p/products/47.609.081.850.2720/yanmar-diesel-engine-720-hp-with-hydraulic-gear

and it works in development level, when i deploy the projects to the hosting server it works for a while as should be, but after a few hours the URI goes some thing like that

http://xxxx.com/(A(6jqh8an0ygEkAAAANTMzMWU2NjgtYTBiNi00ZTQ5LTllZWEtNjI1MGM2MDk5MmY4T_ZQLz3eoy3LgKYYSl0Gk_Sts-A1))/en/p/products/47.609.081.850.2720/yanmar-diesel-engine-720-hp-with-hydraulic-gear

IIS puts Uri on the http address but i never use something other than cookieless="UseCookies" in web.config file.

relevant sections of Web.config file :

```
<sessionState timeout="40" mode="InProc" cookieless="UseCookies" />
<anonymousIdentification enabled="true" cookieless="UseCookies"/>
<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms name="XXXFirmCookie" cookieless="UseCookies"  loginUrl="~/LoginPage.aspx" path="/" protection="All" timeout="60" slidingExpiration="true" requireSSL="false" enableCrossAppRedirects="false" defaultUrl="Default.aspx"></forms>
    </authentication>
```

The odd thing it works on host server for a while without putting uri on the http address.

Host server uses IIS 7.5 and framework is 4.0

Can you see any mistake on my routing code or web.config ?
Or should i check something on IIS ?

Thanks in advance..

Comment: did you ever sort this out?